# Mudar o ponteiro em um bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Possuo um *bootstrap-datepicker*, quando posiciono o mouse em cima do calendário no dia ou então no navegador dos meses o ponteiro que aparece é aquele de seleção, parecido com  `I`, mas gostaria que fosse aquele da mão com o dedo indicador, como poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Datepicker é construído em uma `div` com a `class="datepicker"` (versão *Bootstrap-Datepicker*).

Para que o cursor dentro dessa `div` seja o "dedo indicador" (no CSS = `pointer`), inclua no seu CSS o estilo:

```
.datepicker{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Desta forma, sempre que o cursor entrar no calendário, terá o cursor `pointer`.

```js
$('#calendario').datepicker();
```

```css
.datepicker{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" id="calendario">
```

Comment: seria dentro do style.css?

Comment: coloquei ele dentro do style.css e a mudança não ocorreu, continua com o ponteiro errado, vc poderia me explicar melhor onde essa div ocorre?

Comment: o meu problema é: onde colocar esse trecho de código... pus no style.css e não funcionou, e coloquei e mais um porção de lugares e nenhum deu

Comment: @V.Avancini Fica complicado então, porque não tem como reproduzir o problema. Em vias normais teria que dar certo (execute o exemplo na resposta).

Comment: eu executei o exemplo, vi que funcionou certinho

Comment: @V.Avancini Faz esse teste simples: abra o calendário e deixe-o aberto. Abra o console F12 e execute este código: `$("#ui-datepicker-div").css("cursor","pointer")`... passe o mouse sobre o calendário e veja se fez o efeito.

Comment: não sei como faz pra executar o trecho

Comment: @V.Avancini Abre o console e cole o código na linha de comando e tecle Enter.

Comment: observei que deu um erro no jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load

Answer (score 3):

Minha resposta é bem parecida com as demais utiliza o mesmo conceito de mudar o `cursor`, mas faço por `jquery`:

Basta adicionar o trecho a abaixo:

```
$( ".ui-datepicker-trigger" ).css('cursor','pointer');
```

Segue exemplo conforme as configurações que você comentou:

```js
$('#calendarioIni').datepicker({ 
  minDate: '01/01/1998'
  , maxDate: '31/12/1998'
  , dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
}); 

$( ".ui-datepicker-trigger" ).css('cursor','pointer');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        
<input type="text" id="calendarioIni">
```

Comment: eu tive que fazer algumas definições em JS pro datepicker, se eu fizer isso vai funcionar?

$('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
            startDate: '01/01/1998',
            endDate: '31/12/1998',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
        $( ".ui-datepicker-trigger" ).css('cursor','pointer');

Comment: testei aqui e não rolou

Comment: O estilo no cursor funciona, mas acho que o que você quer fazer com StartDate e endDate, seria o equivalente minDate e maxDate

Comment: aqui tá o contrário, funciona o range mas não funciona o cursor

Comment: Consegue editar sua pergunta e incluir o código? Com um mcve? Isso fara com que nossas respostas sejam mais precisas. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz um pouco diferente do Dvd, porque quando o cursor ficar como `Pointer` o tempo inteiro parece que tudo é clicável, mas nem tudo tem clique. Por isso eu coloque o `cursor:default;` no elemento pai e só usei o `cursor:pointer;` na áreas clicáveis.

No arquivo `jquery-ui.css` vá até o final dos estilos, e faça um override das classes `.ui-datepicker`

```
/* ----- Override de classes -----*/
.ui-datepicker {
    cursor: default;
}
.ui-datepicker a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Aqui tem o link para pegar o CSS do **jquery-ui**: https://jqueryui.com/download/all/

Se quiser usar o link do CDN como no exemplo abaixo, basta colocar dentro da `<head>` da sua página o CSS novo dentro de tags `<style> css com o override </style>` `</head>`

Se vc quiser usar essas classe em um aquivo por exemplo `style.css` vc deve colocar as classes dentro dele e na `<head>` onde vc chama os links dos arquivos deve vir assim: *(Repare que o seu CSS com as classes novas `style.css` deve vir abaixo do `jquery-ui.css`)*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Exemplo com a solução ***Default*** e ***Pointer***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .ui-datepicker {
        cursor: default;
    }
    .ui-datepicker a {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

        
        <input type="text" id="calendario">
<script>
$('#calendario').datepicker();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```